# AngularJs. Understanding ng-model in different controllers

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

Why if you choose on the panel of a rating value, then changing the model and the field value select. But if on the contrary, choose select, then duplicate values on the panel rating is not happening?

Html code:

```
 <select name="post[vote][cinema]" ng-model="cinema" ng-change="set(cinema)">
 <p class="dash ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-mouseleave="reset()" 
    tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" 
    aria-valuenow="4" ng-model="cinema" max="max">
      <a ng-repeat="r in range track by $index" ng-mouseenter="enter($index + 1)" 
          ng-click="rate($index + 1)" ng-class="{...}" class="ng-scope"></a>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smtncL3q/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by injecting `ngModel` in the `rating` directives scope, and assigning a watch on the value.

```
scope: {
    ngModel: '='
},
```

... and then within the link function:

```
scope.$watch('ngModel', function(value) {
    scope.value = value;            
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smtncL3q/2/)

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I forgot that we must think about how the model should follow the directive and not the controller!

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit hard for me to grasp how your JSFiddle exactly works, but I suggest you to use `$parsers` and `$formatters` on your `ngModel`. The parser function updates the model when you click on a rating and the formatter function updates the rating view value when the model is updated by the `select`.

Your solution could be fixed with more hackish code, but it will not improve the readibility.